# Speed up graph editor in Orient DB

Tags: orientdb

I am using orientDB (starting from 2.2.0 to 2.2.6) I have created the graph schema and inserted records (E's and V's) about 50 Millions, my problem is the performance when editing the graph from the web admin console, the problem rendering is very slow and zooming too, also many times i get

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

when I query for large number of records ex. (select from V limit 10000), my question is there any configurations i need to set or if there is any mistake i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

The Graph editor was not designed to work with such amount of nodes (10K).
I Guess even if it was designed for a lot of nodes, 10k seems a lot even for canvas rendering.

You should work with less nodes 1-500